# Using ELMAH and Silverlight together

Tags: silverlight, elmah

Is it possible to redirect exceptions thrown in a Silverlight application to ELMAH?

Answer (score 1):

Check here:
[for an article on how to set up ELMAH to work with Silverlight / WCF services.](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Getting-ELMAH-to-work-with-WCF-services.aspx)

Basically it involves raising the error from inside the Silverlight app.

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [Vincoss logging toolkit](https://github.com/vincoss/vinco-logging-toolkit), works with web, console, wpf, silverlight, wcf and uses ELMAH logging module.